# MYSQLI Count records where one instance of record is flagged

Tags: php, select, mysqli, count

and thank you for any help as this has been driving me nuts and I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.

I am looking to run a very unique MySQLI count : counting all rows in a table where one instance of a common "session" is flagged.

```
 SESSION      PAGE        FLAG
---------------------------------
 1            HOME        0
 1            CONTACT     0
 1            ABOUT US    900
 2            HOME        901
 3            ABOUT US    900
```

For example, in the above table, I am trying to count the total number of instances of sessions that are at some time, flagged 900. In the above example I would get 4 page viewes for sessions flagged 900. I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM analytics WHERE FLAG='900'
```

However, I am missing the rows before the visitor/session was flagged. I am thinking some sort of sub query needs to done?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you have a unique identifier on your rows? or just those 3 columns that you have shown ?

Comment: Yes - I should add I do have a unique primary called RECORD_ID that just autoincrements for the purpose of tracking rows.

Comment: no need in fact. since you only need to count and not to retrieve rows. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM analytics
WHERE session IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT session FROM analytics WHERE FLAG='900' 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the rows unique rows then you can use DISTANT for that for example

```
Select COUNT (DISTANT SESSION)
from analytics
```

Comment: Did you mean `DISTINCT`? I don't know of a DISTANT in mysql. Either way, this doesn't appear take the specific flag into account at all.

Comment: tell me one thing you only count those record where flag is 900